# Removing posted by and date from posts on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, xhtml

How do I remove the date added/admin/no comments section of each one of my posts in my wordpress blog here http://www.kvylfm.com

Comment: You'll just need to edit your theme file and remove the tags that output them.

Comment: Not sure why this got a -1. I say +1 to balance it out since this is a very valid question.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your template file `index.php` and look for this snippet:

```
<div class="post-info clear-block with-thumbs">
```

when you found it, it would be something like this:

```
<div class="post-info clear-block with-thumbs"> 
   <p class="author alignleft">Posted by .........</p>
   <p class="comments alignright">.........</p>
</div>
```

Just remove it all.
If you don't know what template it is, on admin panel, look at `Appearance` » `Editor`.
You should see list of files on right side of that page. Just find `'Main Index Template'` and edit it, look at snippet above then remove it.

Comment: mystique_pagenavi();
       else: ?>
       <h1 class="title error"><?php _e("No posts found","mystique"); ?></h1>
       <p><?php _e("Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.","mystique"); ?></p>

      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php do_action('mystique_after_primary'); ?>
     </div>
    </div>

Comment: Why would it tell me that it is not there?

Comment: I am just not finding it in the main index file. there is very little code in this file so I am not missing something.

Comment: hmm.. it's a custom-custom template. Is there any loop.php file?